# Understanding How Local Git Branches "Track" Remote Branches

Tags: git, branch

This is the `git-sh` output of `branch -a`:

[image]

What does the right arrow `->` mean here?

Does it have anything to do with tracking?

(From what I know, the red branches are  read-only branches from the remote repo.

I understand  that a branch I create in my local GIT repository must be configured to track a specific branch on a remote GIT (so that commands like `pull` can work without specifying the remote branch).

I know that in this repo the only tracking that should be configured is the tracking of my local master to the origin's master. )

Comment: To show tracking information, you have to pass `-vv` to `git branch`

Comment: Do you know what that line with arrow means then?

Comment: That's a symbolic ref. A sym-ref does not point to a specific commit, but to another ref instead (pretty much like the normal `HEAD` special ref)

Comment: So, that line is saying that "remotes/origin/HEAD" points to "origin/master"?  And I assume that "origin/master" is actually the remote branch from the last line "remotes/origin/master" ?

Comment: Yes, origin/HEAD points to origin/master (which is the same origin/master as shown in the last line of output)

Comment: @knittl, This begs the question: Why is the text showing `-> origin/master` instead of `-> remotes/origin/master`? What's the reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: @Pacerier: most of the time you can leave off the `remotes/` part. I don't know the reasoning behind this. Unless you have a local branch with the same name, you can simply use `origin/master` (less visual clutter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow is just a symbolic ref, showing a layer of indirection between remote `origin/HEAD` branch and remote `origin/master` branch.

In order to see tracking you need to add a flag to trigger a higher level of verbosity.  Here's the output of the same command with the `-vv` flag.

[image]

The -vv flag adds verbosity to the output about each branch.  Consider the line for the master branch.  It now gives the SHA-1 hash of the head commit for the branch, and then, in brackets, it tells us the remote branch that the master branch is tracking -- `origin/master`.  This tracking was established by git when we cloned our local repo; master is the only branch for which tracking is auto configured.

Next, I also configured my local `bDev` branch to track the branch of the same name on the `origin` remote.  Note, it's not necessary that the local and tracked remote branch have the same name, but it's common.

Comment: I derived my own answer from @knittl's comments